# Android NDK: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]: 131 cannot locate 'memset'

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a dynamic library compiled for armv7a architecture libmath.so. I need to use this lib in my app so I write C-file for JNI wrapping functions from libmath - math-jni.c.

Android.mk file looks as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := math
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmath.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := math-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := math-jni.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := math
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I build this project using ndk-build I get libmath-jni.so library.

In Java code I call two libraries:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("math");
    System.loadLibrary("math-jni");
}
```

When I run app on Android 4.1.2 device (with armv7a architecture) I get

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError... Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:   131 cannot locate 'memset'...
```

When I run this app on device with Android 4.2.2 or higner (also with armv7a architecture) I get

```
dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.math-1/libmath.so") failed: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:976): cannot locate symbol "memset" referenced by "libmath.so"...
... Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: soinfo_relocate(linker.cpp:976): cannot locate symbol "memset" referenced by "libmath.so"...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **libmath.so** was not built using --no-undefined linker flag, which prohibits the linker to check for undefined symbols; and not properly linked to the lib that defines **memset()**.

You can try to use ndk-depends tool to check what dependencies the library have, and manually load that library before you load libmath.so.

If it still doesn't work, see
[Android NDK Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639016/android-ndk-cannot-load-library-reloc-library1306)
which might help you out a bit.